# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to share file via intent for instagram , but i realized that on API 24++, i can't just share the URI to other app without giving it permission.

Following this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en tutorial, i have set the provider and provide path like this :

Manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="myapplication.file_provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:node="replace">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Note: there is `tools:node=replace" to override provider from library RxPaparazzo.

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>
</paths>
```

Code to save bitmap and get uri

```
public static Uri savePicture(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        int cropHeight;
        if (bitmap.getHeight() > bitmap.getWidth()) cropHeight = bitmap.getWidth();
        else                                        cropHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, cropHeight, cropHeight, ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                context.getString(R.string.app_name)
        );

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = new File(
                mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg"
        );

        // Saving the bitmap
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
            stream.write(out.toByteArray());
            stream.close();

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Mediascanner need to scan for the image saved
        Intent mediaScannerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri fileContentUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        mediaScannerIntent.setData(fileContentUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(mediaScannerIntent);

        return fileContentUri;
    }
```

Composing File Provider Uri

```
Uri savedBitmap = ImageUtility.savePicture(getContext(), shareBitmap);
File media = new File(savedBitmap.getPath());
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "myapplication.file_provider", media);
```

Log Error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains
>   /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Polfaced/IMG_20170203_155130.jpg

Tried using commonware's StreamProvider but i think the library have different purpose (fixing another type of issue), tried saving file to `getFileDirs` instead of `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` but the image is not saved and getting similiar error/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>
</paths>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="."/>
</paths>
```

as described in the link you shared above.

The provider below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>
</paths>
```

will address paths that look like

```
/storage/emulated/0/files/
```

but the paths that you are sharing

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Polfaced/IMG_20170203_155130.jpg
```

does not include or starts with:

```
/storage/emulated/0/files/
```

To understand what

```
path="."
```

does, read the link you shared in detail.