# File Provider: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: java, android, file-sharing, android-fileprovider

I am using FileProvider to share media to other apps with the following code :

```
 Intent shareIntentt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Uri contentUri = Fileprovider.getUriForFile(context, "com.app.tst", csOrignalFile);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntentt, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
```

Here is my provider under `<application>` tag in manifest :

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.app.tst"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

and this is file_paths.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <external-files-path name="external_files" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

The File location is

> data/user/0/com.app.tst/app_Media/User/2b5b73e511c0f40d07303487b9b43a7c4fe92516/df1c010261115ccba4b6ae484aff79714cb23fd5.jpg

I tried multiple answers from SO and changed path="/" with a couple of variations e.g. [FileProvider error "Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/sawbodeployer.entm.illinois.edu ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247796/fileprovider-error-failed-to-find-configured-root-that-contains-data-data-sawb) , [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020506/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-that-contains)
But every time I am getting the same error.

> Process: com.app.tst, PID: 8261
>                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.app.tst/app_Media/User/2b5b73e511c0f40d07303487b9b43a7c4fe92516/df1c010261115ccba4b6ae484aff79714cb23fd5.jpg
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:712)

**Note:** I haven't write any FileProvider of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths >
    <external-path
        name="share" path="/"/>

</paths>
```

instead of `external-files-path`

**Edit:-**
And you also havent done `shareIntent.setData(contentUri);` please set the data too.. :)

Comment: checked `path="."` too ?

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: Oh, Thanks it will help once I succeeded in running Fileprovider.getUriForFile.

Answer (score 0):

set  path="" instead of path="/"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="external_files" path=""/>
</paths>
```

Comment: And if I run it (ignoring the error) it has still the same issue.

Comment: your path is vaild?

Comment: this is the path data/user/0/com.app.tst/app_Media/User/2b5b73e511c0f40d07303487b9b43a7c4fe92516/df1c010261115ccba4b6ae484aff79714cb23fd5.jpg and yes it is valid. 

I am creating new file as 'File csOrignalFile = new File("data/user/0/com.app.tst/app_Media/User/2b5b73e511c0f40d07303487b9b43a7c4fe92516/df1c010261115ccba4b6ae484aff79714cb23fd5.jpg");'

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248855/how-to-set-fileprovider-for-file-in-external-cache-dir/35220426#35220426

Answer (score 0):

```
<external-files-path name="external_files" path="/"/>
```

Change to

```
<files-path name="myfiles" path="."/>
```

And

```
data/user/0/com.app.tst/app_Media/User/2b5.....
```

Change to

```
/data/user/0/com.app.tst/files/app_Media/User/2b5b73e51.....
```

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: ??? Did you move your files to the ..../files/... dir then? You have to!

Comment: No. I didn't. I don't want to move my file to any different dir

Comment: Then sorry you cannot use FileProvider class. It wil not serve from there.

Comment: Can I ask why??

Comment: Its how its programmed. FileProvider will only serve from some predetermined paths. Just read the developers page.